# How to find a and b estimates in regression from least square error formula

Tags: regression, linear-regression

In regression, we want to minimize $1/n \sum_1^n(y_i-(a+bx_i))^2 $. To minimize, we use gradients:
$$\begin{align} \partial/\partial b = 0 \Rightarrow \sum_i^n x_i(y_i-(a+bx_i)) =0 \Rightarrow
\sum_1^nx_iy_i-a\sum x_i-b\sum x_i^2=0 \end{align}$$
$$\partial/\partial a = 0 \Rightarrow 
\sum_i^n (y_i-(a+bx_i))=0 \Rightarrow \\
\sum y_i - \sum a -b\sum x_i = 0  \Rightarrow \\
 \sum y_i - na -b\sum x_i = 0 $$

which eventually in the second equation we have $na$ which I can't find a way to properly get rid of to get to the formalization of $\hat b = \frac{\overline {XY} -\overline X \overline Y}{\overline {X^2} - \overline X^2}$ where $\overline {XY} ,$ $\overline X,$ and $\overline Y $ represent averages. Can someone explain where I am going wrong?

Comment: Just note that $\sum_{i=1}^n a = na$. That way you "get rid of" your $\sum a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your first equation can be written as $\overline{XY}-a\overline{X}-b\overline{X^2}=0$ and then second can be written as $-a=b\overline{X}-\overline{Y}$ plugging $-a$ into the first $\overline{XY}-(b\overline{X}-\overline{Y})\overline{X}-b\overline{X^2}=0\iff b(\overline{X}^2-\overline{X^2})=\overline{X}\overline{Y}-\overline{XY}$ as desired

Comment: but the second one is $-na = b \overline X - \overline Y$ so how did you get rid of the n coefficient for a?

Comment: You need to divide by n to get the averages

Comment: oh! That makes so much sense! I don't know why I kept missing that!